# Maven build fails while using JCE with " The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by a trusted signer!"

Tags: java, security, maven, permissions, jce

I am using the JCE to encrypt and decrypt in my project. I have installed the necessary java security jars under $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security. Also in my development environment in eclipse I am pointing to the correct jre. Everything works fine in eclipse. But when I build the project with maven , it fails with the following exeption

```
 The jurisdiction policy files are not signed by a trusted signer!
```

Things tried so far.

Tried a hack by initializing the following block of code before anything else

```
 try {
    Field field = Class.forName("javax.crypto.JceSecurity").getDeclaredField("isRestricted");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(null, java.lang.Boolean.FALSE);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException | IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Also tried changing the pom.xml by adding the following plugin

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.1</version>
 <executions>
     <execution>
         <id>enforce</id>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                  <evaluateBeanshell>
                     <condition>javax.crypto.Cipher.getMaxAllowedKeyLength("AES") > 128</condition>
                  </evaluateBeanshell>
             </rules>
         </configuration>
         <goals>
             <goal>enforce</goal>
         </goals>
      </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

I have confirmed that the version of the policy jars matches the Java version on my machine.  Is there a way to configure maven to use these jars?  (Without having to use another library like Bouncy Castle) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) in order to get the unlimited strength version and use it for both build and runtime.